# How to calculate the probability of a repeating pattern of outcomes within a sequence of events (specific situation)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

I have a sequence of 54 events (Likert-scale survey items). The outcomes of these events (item responses) correspond to integers.

I need to find the probability (assuming all outcomes for each event are equally likely) of ANY pattern of outcomes repeating 3 or more times consecutively OR of a single outcome repeating 6 times consecutively. The length of the repeating pattern does not matter (i.e. it could be 2 outcomes repeating, such as "4,5,4,5,4,5", or up to 18 items repeating) so long as the pattern repeats 3 times consecutively.

To complicate matters, some events have different numbers of possible outcomes.

The first 22 events have 6 possible outcomes (Outcomes 0 through 5).
The next 10 events (events 23 through 32) have 5 possible outcomes (Outcomes 1 through 5).
The final 22 events (events 33 through 54) have 7 possible outcomes (Outcomes 1 through 7).

Thus, 5 outcomes (Outcomes 1 through 5) are possible throughout all events, while outcome 0 is only present in events 1 through 22, and outcomes 6 and 7 are only present in events 33 through 54).

I figured out how to calculate the number of distinct patterns (I actually made an error in calculation, but I know how to correct it). However, I then realized that this figure did not account for the various combinations of all the possible combination of outcomes not implicated in the pattern itself. That would be straightforward enough, but I realized that simply multiplying the number of patterns of each length by the number of combinations of non-pattern outcomes would be substantially inflating the probability of a pattern occurring by including combinations of outcomes which also included other patterns.

Could anyone suggest a formula for calculating this probability? I need the actual method/formula you would use to check your work. Also, an answer taking the form of "Probability would be less than" would be acceptable if it were reasonably close to correct and saved some effort in accounting for double counting patterns (e.g. double counting smaller patterns within larger ones, such as the fact that the set of every possible 4-event-long pattern also includes the entire set of every possible 2-event-long pattern). However, answers of the form "probability would be greater than" would not be useful, as I am trying to justify the conclusion that these events are unlikely, or identify a similar criteria that would be unlikely.

Thanks everyone, sorry I am stumped on this, and just realized I drove myself nuts pursuing a solution that was actually wrong. Also, I am in the social sciences, so I apologize if I'm using any statistical terminology incorrectly.

Comment: Would a computer-based solution be helpful? (The chances of doing this correctly by hand seem slim.)

Comment: Yes, it definitely could be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4884681.java) that performs inclusion–exclusion for this problem. I don’t see a way to make an exact solution tractable, but part of the beauty of inclusion–exclusion is that it gives you alternating upper and lower bounds on the desired count. In the present case, the bounds from the first four stages may already be sufficiently tight for your purposes. They are

\begin{align}
p\lt\frac{401720233802817099323960526777224873}{10721193919434425014594534361530368000}&\approx0.03746972928776285\;,
\\
p\gt\frac{4201948007014679218289498623445742497411}{143587418563853906445462513770496000000000}&\approx0.029264040324995855\;,
\\
p\lt\frac{1748294416292362535737205604304327179703}{55839551663720963617679866466304000000000}&\approx0.03130924880667034\;,
\\
p\gt\frac{4385318275113451134817187683255378685393}{143587418563853906445462513770496000000000}&\approx0.03054110394193961\;,
\end{align}

where $p$ is the probability that at least one of the repeating patterns occurs. (Note that the event of a single outcome repeating $6$ times doesn’t need to be considered separately, since it’s a pattern of $2$ identical outcomes repeating $3$ times.)

The next bound would again be an upper bound, which you said is more useful for you, but the fourth stage already took $2$ hours to compute and the fifth stage would take about $100$ times as long, so I’ll wait whether $3.054\%\lt p\lt3.131\%$ is good enough for you. Anyway, we already know from the lower bound that the next upper bound can’t be much of an improvement.

The code works by considering the $425$ conditions imposed ($54-3\ell+1$ conditions for patterns of length $\ell$, one for each possible starting position) and, for the $k$-th stage of inclusion–exclusion, forming all $k$-tuples of conditions and counting the configurations that fulfil all $k$ conditions. This it does by representing the conditions as sets of sets of events, with each set of events representing the constraint that the outcomes of those events must be identical. For instance, a pattern of length $2$ repeated $3$ times starting from event $1$ is represented by the set $\{\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\}\}$ of sets of events, since the outcomes of events $1$, $3$ and $5$ must be identical, as must the outcomes of events $2$, $4$, $6$. The conjunction of conditions represented in this form can efficiently be computed with logical bit operations.

The specification of the problem (the number of events and the range of outcomes of each event) is at the top of the code, so while you can’t check the results for the actual problem, you can change the specification without delving deep into the code, so you can make it solve a problem that you can check by hand. As a further check, [here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4884681Simulation.java) that simulates the experiment. The result from $10^8$ samples is a probability of $0.03080\pm0.00002$, in agreement with the bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joriki, this is incredibly helpful, and I really appreciate your time! These solutions are more than sufficient. The calculation is going to be used to justify a data inclusion determination, given some other indications of validity problems with a subset of the data. Given that hypotheses are being tested at an alpha of 0.05, roughly 3.1% is more than sufficiently accurate (and unlikely) to justify using the criteria to exclude responses. I'll play with the code a bit on problems I can solve by hand to satisfy myself, but this was immensely helpful! I really appreciate it!